# How to connect a line signal to a guitar amp?

Tags: amplifiers, electronics, construction, speakers, equipment

My Laney Lv300 Tube Fusion Combo amp, doesn't have a Line-In, as such. It merely has one "Input" on the front, for the guitar and a pair of FX sockets, as an FX Loop (FX Send and FX Return). It also has one "Speaker Out" socket, for connection to an 8ohm-plus extension speaker.

What I need to know is this, is there any way for me to connect an MP3 player for example, to this amp?? I know that it is a Valve Driven Pre-amp Combo and that the two inbuilt 12" Celestions may not be the correct ones to give me an excellent audio out for general music, but my requirement is just to be able to generate an acceptable audio outside, for a forthcoming Open Day. I do also understand that the potential Stereo output from the MP3 player will have to be resolved to mono.

I do have a pair of 8ohm PA speakers that I can use as well. I plan to plug one extension speaker, into the single provided extension socket and I also plan to install a separate second output socket, into the rear of the amp cabinet, using a switched 1/4" Phone socket, that should then isolate the inbuilt speakers, when the extension is plugged into it. That will allow me to run at the minimum 4ohms that the amp requires.

Any thoughts, comments or suggestions on the best way to do all of this, would REALLY be appreciated. The speaker mod, I am sure that I can resolve, but the method of connecting an MP3 type player into the amp, to play music for the masses on that day, is something that I am desperate to sort out.

Thanking you in advance for ANY help with this....John.

I have managed to partially answer my own question. I dug out an old Vestax PCV-150 that I have and ran a 3.5 stereo jack from the player, which terminates in 2 phono jacks that I plugged into one of the Line input banks on the Vestax. The output from the Vestax, has been taken from one of the two "Sub-Master" 1/4" sockets, connected through a standard guitar lead, into the Laney amp Input. I plan to try using a "split lead "Y" connector", which will allow me to use both of the Sub-Master Outputs from the Vestax, as soon as I have one available, whilst still using the guitar lead into the amp.

Latest update.... I purchased a 1/4" "Y" split lead recently and connected the joined "Y" end, into both of the Sub-master output connectors on the Vestax. As previously, I then connected the remaining portion of the "Y" lead, into the Laney Input. This appears to now work exactly as I need it to. Thank you to everyone that has posted comments here, to help me with this. I hope that this post ends up being of help to others, in a similar predicament to myself.

Comment: @Felinas are you planning to play guitar at the same time as the mp3 tracks? (Like using backing tracks…)

Comment: The plan is Bob, just to use the amp that day, as a PA system for playing music for the masses. I don't plan to inflict my playing on them ;) lol

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to a looper pedal, such as the Boss RC series, they have a line in. Connect the pedal to the looper, and then your MP3 player to the line in of the loop pedal.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't have access to an Effects Looper at the moment, but it is certainly something to look at.

Comment: As I had managed to dig out an old Vestax PCV-150 mixer that I have, I tried to utilize the FX Loop connections on it, into the "Send" and "Return" sockets on the Laney amp. As above, I connected the player into the same Line Input bank, but I could get absolutely no output from the amp at all. A rethink is required on that option, I think.

Comment: @Felinis: The mixer sends a signal and receives it back, possibly modified with effects. The guitar amplifier also sends a signal and receives it back, possibly modified with effects. Connecting an amplifier and a mixer in this way is hence not likely to give good results... I don't think the signal types are the same either.

Answer (score 4):

I'd have thought that merely plugging the player into the input would do the job. The volume can be attenuated via the gain pot on the amp., and also by the volume control on the player. Turn it down initially, as there will be a propensity for lots of sound. The speaker extension output - it may already be switched, and cuts out the internal speakers of the amp. Make sure that you wire either in series or parallel to reach a sensible impedance for the amp. to cope with, especially if the internal speakers are still functioning when others are plugged in.

Comment: I did consider using a stereo 3.5mm jack from the MP3, then down to a shorted (combined positives) mono 6.35mm (1/4"), jack patch lead and using it the way that you have suggested, but it has been suggested elsewhere, that just combining the 2 stereo positives, could lead to problems with the MP3 player :( The amp itself does not switch off the two internal speakers, when the supplied extension speaker jack is used, as it is designed to allow the existing speakers to play in tandem with the new extension cabinet.

Comment: I've done it with cassette players , CD players and minidisc players which came to no harm, but mp3 is far too modern for me! With such a small output voltage it SHOULD be o.k. Maybe check with the manufacturer.

Comment: Thanks for that Tim :) It is certainly still a serious option, but I now at least have room for thought from a couple of the comments made to date. Yours definitely included ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a passive DI box and run it backwards, or get a specialized box called a ReAmp to do this.

Comment: That appears to be a "Muchos Dineros" option, for a one off use unfortunately Dan :(

Comment: @Felinis DI and ReAmp boxes can be both cheap and good at the same time. http://www.sweetwater.com/c957--Direct_Boxes/low2high/

Answer (score 1):

The effects loop on a guitar amplifier is between the preamp (where the gain and EQ controls sit to modify the tone) and the power amplifier (which pretty much just makes everything louder). Your [specific amplifier](http://www.laney.co.uk/products/product_details/90) has a multi-channel tube preamp with a solid state power amp.

As your amplifier has an effects loop, you can feed a non-guitar input in through the FX Return input. This has the advantage that the audio is not going through the preamp, which will significantly affect the tone, but straight into the power amp, which tends to have flatter tonal response.

Another advantage of this is that it allows you to play along - some amps have a an effects loop blend control between the dry signal (direct preamp -> power amp) and the wet signal (via FX loop), which you can use to mix the input with the guitar. I have also used this technique to use a single 100W amp for two guitars: one through the pre-amp, one through an external amp simulator into the FX return.